# Identity resolution with RegEx

Tags: python, r, regex

I have a list of authors of papers that benefits from identity resolution!
As an example, it should match these names:

```
Peter J. Smith
Peter Smith
P.J. Smith
P. J. Smith (works with space or without it)
p.j. smith
```

I'm new to RegEx. I'd like to write a RegEx in R/Python that match the initial of the first name and the whole last name and ignore the middle name. (Although, this method will have some issues, for example there are occurrences of names such as Peter L. Smith but I think considering the middle name will complicate things.) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show us what you've tried...

Comment: see if this help you. https://regex101.com/r/uOhrCb/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `L` in the Note at the end try taking the first letter plus everything after the last space and passing that through one of the algorithms in the phonics package.  In this example it did correctly map all variations of Peter Smith to the same code while distinguishing Peter Sorensen with a different code.

```
library(phonics)

onca(sub("^(.).* (.*)", "\\1 \\2", trimws(L)))
## [1] "P253" "P253" "P253" "P253" "P253" "P265"
```

That package also has soundex and other algorithms that you can try out.

### Note

```
L <- c("Peter J. Smith", "Peter Smith", "P.J. Smith", "P. J. Smith", "p.j. smith", 
 "Peter Sorensen")
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we avoid matching "Paul Smith" with "Peter Smith"?

Comment: You will have to play around with variations based on your list.  It is unlikely will get 100% accuracy.